# How do I use bold font in terminal? (echo/cat)

Tags: command-line

How can I make some output bold in Ubuntu terminal

```
echo "text bold text"

text bold text
```

or the same from

```
cat my_file
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's how:

```
echo -e "text \033[1mbold\033[0m text"
```

See ["Colorizing" Scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html) tutorial.

It's not possible to do for `cat` that way. `cat` will merely print the characters of the file onto standard out. The closest thing I can come up with is the following:

If you put `text \033[1mbold\033[0m text` you can do

```
echo -e `cat test.txt`
```

Comment: what I wanted in cat is the same. I do
'echo -e "text \033[1mbold\033[0m text" > myfile' and then
'cat myfile'

thank you for showing this.

Comment: More generally, "echo $(tput bold)" and "echo $(tput sgr0)" will work for any terminal, not just ANSI/VTxxx-compatible ones.

Comment: @njd, ah, good point.

Answer (score 6):

Also checkout [tput(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput). Based on [ncurses(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) which is a system abstraction for terminal manipulation (i.e. its purpose is to bring an API which works independent of architecture, OS, terminal, tty, etc.).

Example:

```
echo "$(tput bold)AHHH$(tput sgr0)"
```

Hehe, asked 10 years ago; I'm too useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can "cat" a file in bold by doing command substitution.

```
echo -e "text \033[1m`cat my_file`\033[0m text"
```

"Command substitution reassigns the output of a command or even multiple commands; it literally plugs the command output into another context."

So the magic part here is

```
`cat my_file`  # or $(cat my_file)
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Backticks will be portable to legacy shells, while I prefer to use `$()`.